# Using CSS to left-pad a cell with a variable amount

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to present a hierarchy within a table.

```
Caninae
 Canis                   
  adustus                Side-Striped Jackel
  anthus                 African Golden Wolf
  aureus                 Golden Jackel
  latrans                Coyote
  lupus                  Grey Wolf
 Cerdocyon
  thous                  Crab-eating Fox
Felidae
 Panthera
  leo                    Lion
```

I would like the child rows indented one level more than the parent. I could easily do this by pre-defining a bunch of classes, like `.level1{padding-left: 10px;}` and `.level2{padding-left: 20px;}`.

However, some end user will eventually add more children of children than I would define. Is there "one simple trick" to accomplish this without CSS, or a better CSS technique. I could query the database and generate the CSS on the fly on each page call, or I could embed the padding with `<td style="padding-left=10px">CONTENT</td>`. The last is probably the most flexible, but there's the whole "Keep your CSS out of your HTML" thing.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: This feels like this should be tables within tables not a single table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nested `<span>`  approach:

if the database returns the following as `$results`:

```
id       pid              name          description
1        0                Caninae
2        1                Canis                   
3        2                adustus       Side-Striped Jackel
4        2                anthus        African Golden Wolf
5        2                aureus        Golden Jackel
```

You can create the table above by:

```
function print_table(){
  $results = some_sql_function();
  //$hierarchy contains an array of childern and an array of data
  $hierarchy = create_hierarchy($results);

  $data = $hierarchy['data'];
  $index = $hierarchy['index'];

  //Create the table header
  $output = "<table>";

  $header = "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Description</th></tr>";
  $output .= $header;

  $rows = create_rows($data, 0, $index, 0);
  $output .= $rows . "</table>";

  echo $output;
}

// Iterating function to nest the childern rows beneith the parents 
function create_rows($data, $parent_id, $index, $level){
  $rows = "";
  if (isset($index[$parent_id])) {
    foreach ($index[$parent_id] as $id) {
      $cell1 = str_repeat('<span style="padding-left:20px">',$level) . $data[$id]["name"] . str_repeat('</span>',$level);
      $cell2 =$data[$id]['description'];
      $row = "<tr><td>$cell1</td><td>$cell2</td></tr>";
      $rows .= $row;
      $rows .= create_rows($data, $id, $index, $level + 1));
    }
  }
  return $rows;
}

function create_hierarchy($results) {
  //The data associated with each account
  $data = array();

  //A list of an account's children
  $index[] = array();
  foreach ($results as $row){
    $id = $row->id;
    $name = $row->name;
    $parent_id = $row->pid;
    $description = $row->description;
    $data[$id] = array('name'=>$name, 'description'=>$description);
    $index[$parent_id][] = $id;
  }

  $hierarchy = array('data'=>$data, 'index'=>$index);

  return $hierarchy;
}
```

I modified my Drupal code to be plain PHP, so there might be a few tiny bugs, but this is what I did.

Comment: A slightly better modification would be, instead of nesting '<span>` elements, I should make one, and calculate the padding based on the level: `$padding = 20*$level;  $cell1 = '<span style="padding-left:' . $padding . 'px">' . $data[$id]["name"] . '</span>';

Answer (score 3):

If you can modify your html, you can use a hierarchy structure like `<li>`

```css
ul, li { padding:0; margin:0; list-style-type:none; } /** reset **/
li {padding-left:20px;} /** important rule */
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Content
    <ul>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content
        <ul>
          <li>Content</li>
          <li>Content</li>
          <li>Content</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Content</li>
  <li>Content</li>
  <li>Content</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not sure how helpful this is since a table is not only generated but the optimal structure here.

Comment: This is a good answer. I suppose if the OP has to use tables, they can use nested tables instead with the same idea.

Comment: I agree though tables would be optimal.

Comment: The list is currently displayed as a list, but the "descriptions" are all over the place and not in a nice column like they would be in a table.  I have currently created a table, but placed a leading number of dashes to perform the indentations. If I could add a `nbsp;` I would, but I'm pretty sure leading non-breaking spaces are not rendered inside tables, right?

Comment: @Andrew, instead of nested tables, can you nest `<span>` elements, where each has 10 pixels of left padding?

Comment: I think this is neater, much less markup than a table, but still semantic. @KevinNowaczyk for the column info (descriptions) you can easily create paragraph or span elements inside the list (and potentially use class names), and then use relative positioning to offset them so they line up. Or fixed with for the first column.

Comment: @KevinNowaczyk You could do that but spans are inline elements and they are not really made for displaying data this way. You could use a table and then use the nested spans for just the first column (this way only the first columns would be indented and not the whole rows). Is there any reason why you can't use nested tables or lists?

Comment: If you use spans you would have to add line-breaks after each row.

Comment: You can put almost any element inside an li though, so it's pretty flexible.

Comment: @Andrew. Nested tables are a nightmare due to code clutter and semantics. Divs and spans would be better. Also, I'm doing this within Drupal, so adding the CMS layer on top of this will be extra difficult.  I actually tried adding nested span elements around the content of the first column and it looks good, so I think That's what I'll do.